# Having trouble with conditionals in Swift

Tags: swift

I am stuck on the following problem set. Any ideas?

```
var hasFuel == "true"

if hasFuel == "true" {
    print("Let's go for a drive")
} else if hasFuel != "true" {
    print("We're not going anywhere!")
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? what are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Why is `hasFuel` a String and not a Bool? What's the point of the second `if`? You already know it's unequal to `"true"` in the `else`.

Comment: I am guessing that ´var hasFuel == "true"´ should only have one ´=´ and that this will solve the problem. next time, please post the exact problem statement given, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *assignment operator vs. equality operator* mistake.

The code doesn't compile

> '==' is not a prefix unary operator

You probably want to **assign** the value

```
var hasFuel = "true"
```

better

```
var hasFuel = true
```

this avoids the second `if`

```
if hasFuel == true {
    print("Let's go for a drive")
} else {
    print("We're not going anywhere!")
}
```

or still shorter

```
if hasFuel {
    print("Let's go for a drive")
} else {
    print("We're not going anywhere!")
}
```